# Guests/Read only users see different search layout to admins

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I spent quite a while making a custom search for our site.
I removed the ability to view library, share, edit etc and even added extra column details into the search results. I was happy.

I noticed however that guests/read only users don't see this customisation. They see the same results, but in the standard sharepoint format. Filename, some text, url to file.

I've had the search on both screens, one with read only, one admin and they are different. Why is this? How can I get guests to view the custom search results view which I am seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your custom page/layout is [published as a "major version"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/publish-or-unpublish-a-version-of-a-file-8766f85c-350d-46f3-9a80-42de99aff610), and potentially if [content approval is enabled](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/require-approval-of-items-in-a-site-list-or-library-cd0761c4-8c3f-4ea2-9435-13c28aa23d08), then also make sure your changes are "approved".

Typically, if privileged users can see your changes while unprivileged users cannot, it is one of those two things or both.